# Initialize using patchValue for template driven forms

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I use template driven and am trying to initialize my form using patchValue and it is not working.

I can make it work if I use two-way binding to set values [(fooBar)] or even setTimeout but I was just wondering, is there a way to make it work with just patchValue?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fft2c5

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because **at the time of calling** `patchValue` **method there are no any controls registered in your form yet**.

Why?

That's because **Template-driven forms are** **asynchronous**. They delegate creation of their form controls to directives. To avoid "changed after checked" errors, these directives take more than one cycle to build the entire control tree. That means **you must wait a tick before manipulating any of the controls from within the component class**.

Moreover, if you try using `setValue` method instead of `patchValue` Angular will even warn you how to deal with it.

```
this.myForm.control.setValue({name: this.name});
```

> ERROR Error: There are no form controls registered with this group
>   yet. If you're using ngModel, you may want to check next tick (e.g.
>   use setTimeout).

So, as you already discovered, you have to either use `[ngModel]` binding or wait next tick by using e.g `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame`

Scheduling microtask should also work if you would use it in ngAfterViewInit hook:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    this.myForm.control.patchValue({ name: this.name });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a very clear explanation on this! I can validate that the microtask approach works as well.

Comment: Very nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In template driven forms, you need to bind `[(ngModel]` to set values.

Try like this:

.html

```
<input name="name" [(ngModel)]="formValue.name"/>
```

.ts

```
formValue:any = {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.formValue = {name: this.name}
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a91fxj)**