# Angular NgForm.setValue({}) with optional fields

Tags: typescript, angular-template-form

I have a Template driven form in angular,
on which i want to populate valuees when i click on a product.
The fields 'description' and 'imageUrl' might be undefined which break my form if i don't take care of it.
I managed to do it with this solution :

```js
  private initFormEdit() {
    this.product = this.productService.fetchProduct(this.restaurantId, this.productId);

    // I'm using a ternaty operator to put a default value if objects are empty
    const description = this.product.description ? this.product.description : '';
    const imageUrl = this.product.imageUrl ? this.product.imageUrl : '';

    this.productForm.setValue({
      name: this.product.name,
      category: this.product.category,
      description,
      price: this.product.price,
      imageUrl
    });
  }
```

Is there a simpler or cleaner way to do that ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular has `patchValue` and `setValue`

While `setValue` expects every field defined in the form to be supplied, `patchValue`does not.

so in your example

```
// this throws
this.productForm.form.setValue({
      name: this.product.name,
      category: this.product.category,
      price: this.product.price,
    });

//this does not throw
this.productForm.form.patchValue({
      name: this.product.name,
      category: this.product.category,
      price: this.product.price,
    });
```

this is valid for `patchValue` but not `setValue` -> use patchValue for your case

Notice that the form itself holds a `formGroup` called `form` you have to use because `ngForm` doesn't have the `patchValue` method.

**UPDATE**
There are [some caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674775/initialize-using-patchvalue-for-template-driven-forms) using `pachValue` with template driven forms depending on when you call `patchValue`.
You could also use somekind of mapper/initializer where you set every missing or undefined member of your object.
Personally I would go with the `patchValue` route if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but actually patchValue() doesn't exists for NgForm (template Driven Form) if i'm not wrong

Comment: `patchValue` does actually exists for template driven forms.
But there are some caveats as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674775/initialize-using-patchvalue-for-template-driven-forms).
Another way would be to create some kind of initializer where you initialize any missing/undefined member.
I updated my answer.

Comment: Oh i see why i didn't find the patchValue method, there is a small mistake in what you wrote. PatchValue is not a method of NgForm class but of FormGroup Class. So it works with a little change : ```this.productForm.control.patchValue({name: this.product.name,category: this.product.category,price: this.product.price,description: this.product.description,imageUrl: this.product.imageUrl});
      }); ``` Now it doesn't throws anymore. Thanks a lot !

Comment: you are right, I updated my answer.
If it helped you I'd appreciate when you accept it :)

Comment: Done ! Thank you !